# What is the difference between Common Goods and Common Pool Resources?

Tags: microeconomics, commons

All this time I was thinking that common-pool resources are common goods, until I read this excerpt from a book. 
[image: It is an Excerpt from a book by Elinor Ostrom]

Comment: Do "common goods", "collective goods" and "public goods" to refer to the same thing?

Comment: The term used in your quote is "collective goods", not "common goods".

Answer (score 3):

Common pool resources can be depleted by overuse.

For example, an area of communal grazing land would be a common pool resource because grazing too many animals decreases the amount of grass available to each animal.

Wikipedia is a common good but are not a common pool resource - reading a lot of articles on Wikipedia does not reduce the number of articles available for everyone else to read.

Comment: Can Wikipedia be considered as a Common Good?

According to theory I have come across, for something to be a public good it has to be non-excludable and non-rival. 
For example, sunshine. Can you exclude people from enjoying sunshine? Nope. No one can be excluded.
Does sunshine have any rival, that if I am using it, someone else cannot use it? Nope. Anyone can use it. 

So, sunshine is non-rival and non-excludable. So, it is a public good.

Same goes for Wikipedia as well, that no one can be excluded from using it, and if I use Wikipedia does not mean other person cannot use it.

Answer (score 2):

A useful reference is the matrix proposed by Elinor Ostrom:

[image]
Source: [Hess & Ostrom (2007)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/239919282_Introduction_An_Overview_of_the_Knowledge_Commons)

**Common-pool resources** (= **Common goods**, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_good_(economics))):
using them impacts others + exclusion is difficult (e.g. the climate)

**Public goods** (= **Collective goods**, [Source](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1573442087800046)):
using them does not impact others + exclusion is difficult (e.g. knowledge)

i.e. what Taylor says is that privatising the atmosphere would not resolve the collective action problem; although it would make sense given that its use is subtractable (= rivalrous) it cannot be done because exclusion is difficult.